# How to change the axis of rotation

Tags: animation

[image][image]

Like seen in the picture, i want this minigun rotating and want to animate  it, but i dont know how to do this while keeping the y rotation constant.

Comment: are you talking about the 2 guns? and what do you mean by "keeping the y rotation constant"?

Comment: yes i mean these two miniguns and i want them to rotate i their own z axis, like seen in the added picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here is what you can do:

- Create you gun, keep it aligned on the global Z axis, animate a 180° rotation on the global Z axis.
- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> on the *Dopesheet* to create a *Linear Extrapolation*.
- Create an empty on its bottom.
- Parent the gun to the empty.
- Tilt the empty the way you want (15° if the angle between the 2 guns is 30°).
- Now your gun rotates on the empty angle.
- Duplicate the gun + the empty to create you second gun, tilt them 30° in *Front Ortho* view (or 180° on the Z axis). You now have your two guns.

[image]